# mat-menu styles not being applied in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to create a simple layout in angular 2 using angular material and flex css..

### Below is my code...

```
<div  class="background" >

<mat-toolbar fxLayout="row"   fxLayoutAlign="space-between  none" >

<div  fxLayout="column" > 
<p>SPACE STUDY</p>
<h6>Rockefeller FY 2018</h6>

<div  fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start none">

 <h6 [matMenuTriggerFor]="dashboarditems">
  <mat-icon style="transform: scale(1.2);">line_weight</mat-icon> </h6>

  <mat-menu  class="mat-menu-panel"  [overlapTrigger]="true" #dashboarditems="matMenu"><br/><br/>
<a  routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive='active'>
<span matTooltip="HOME"><mat-icon style="color:lightgreen;">home</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="SPACE SURVEY"><mat-icon style="color:deeppink;">explore</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a  >
<span matTooltip="SPACE ADMIN"><mat-icon style="color:lightblue;">account_circle</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="REPORTS"><mat-icon style="color: orange;">assignment</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a >
<span matTooltip="JOINT USE"><mat-icon style="color:yellow;">supervisor_account</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>

<a  >
<span matTooltip="HELP"><mat-icon style="color:red;">help</mat-icon></span></a><br/><br/><br/>
  </mat-menu>
</div>


</div>

<div fxLayout="row"  fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true" >
<button mat-raised-button routerLink='/home' routerLinkActive='active'>
<span matTooltip="HOME"><mat-icon style="color:lightgreen;">home</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="SPACE SURVEY"><mat-icon style="color:deeppink;">explore</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="SPACE ADMIN"><mat-icon style="color:lightblue;">account_circle</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="REPORTS"><mat-icon style="color: orange;">assignment</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button  >
<span matTooltip="JOINT USE"><mat-icon style="color:yellow;">supervisor_account</mat-icon></span></button>

<button mat-raised-button >
<span matTooltip="HELP"><mat-icon style="color:red;">help</mat-icon></span></button>
</div>

</mat-toolbar>

</div>


<style>

.background {
/* Remember to use the other versions for IE 10 and older browsers! */
display: flex;
min-height: 100%;
font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
color: #fff;
height:100vh;
background: #222222;
background: #16222A; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #16222A , #3A6073); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to top, #16222A , #3A6073); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

p{
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
margin:3px;
}

h6{
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
}

.mat-raised-button{
    text-align:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    background:transparent;
}

.mat-icon {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

.matTooltip{
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
    }

.mat-menu-panel {
    min-width: 35px;
    max-width: 280px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: 0;
    background: transparent;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
</style>
```

### This is my output

[image]

Here I am trying to change the background color for the mat-menu container to transparent and also set some other styles.

When i change in console its getting reflected back as shown below

[image]

But when i applied the same changes in my code , the styles are not being applied.

I also tries explicitly adding class="mat-menu-panel" in the component and the div in which i added the mat-menu.

But still the styles are not being applied..

can anybody please help me to fix this styling..

please access my sample code here.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-vc3fsj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: still your code is broken please fix that

Comment: Your stackblitz snippet does not run

Comment: can you please access this link  ...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-vc3fsj?file=index.html

Comment: @Heena not sure how to phrase this differently, that link does not work

Comment: Any custom styling to mat-menu is best done in the theme .scss file. In your `style.scss` file you already put rules for body, try adding the mat-menu styles there. A good resource to check out is this one https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/05/23/custom-themes-with-angular-material.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have styles in your html template. You need to put them in separate stylesheet. Once you've done that, it may  not work for styling material components,  because of angular's default style encapsulation.

You can

**set the styles to global styles.css file**

Style.css

```
.mat-menu-panel {
min-width: 35px;
```

**use the ng-deep combinator**

Put your styles in component specific stylesheet

Component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep  .mat-menu-panel {
min-width: 35px;
/* ...*/
```

**Change the component' s encapsulation**

Put your styles in component specific stylesheet and change the component' s code

Component.ts

```
@Component({
//...
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None 
 })
```

With that last one, styles will leak to entire app (like in global style sheet)

Comment: encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None is not a good idea at all

Comment: just apply you css style directly on the class ( .mat-menu-item, .mat-menu-wrapper etc )

Comment: note that you can already do the following ::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel { ... }

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
::ng-deep.mat-menu-panel {}
```

note that you can handle the following classes .mat-menu-item, .mat.menu-wrapper etc directly
**Note that you shouldn't use them inside another css class in the componenet.scss**

Answer (score 1):

can you check this one i have written some css style inside styles.scss
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-formfield-flex-layout-lvns7f?file=styles.scss